# Javascript function definition/call difference between browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox

Recently I noticed a behavior difference between Firefox and other browsers for the following javascript code:

```
var condition = true;
A();

function A() {

    var x=0;

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if(condition) {
            ++x;
            B();
        }

        function B() {
                console.log("B function. x = "+x);
        }
    }
}
```

Chrome, Opera, IE output:

```
B function. x = 1
B function. x = 2 
B function. x = 3
B function. x = 4
B function. x = 5
B function. x = 6
B function. x = 7
B function. x = 8
B function. x = 9
B function. x = 10
```

Firefox output:

```
ReferenceError: B is not defined
```

However, there are **no complaints** from Firefox and gives out the **same result** as other browsers, if I put the definition of `function B` before the call, like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {

        function B() {
                console.log("B function. x = "+x);
        }

        if(condition) {
            ++x;
            B();
        }
    }
```

Based on this quote from Mozilla developer site:

> Functions must be in scope when they are called, but the function declaration can be below the call

I understand the call, `A()` works. But I am not clear on why there is a difference in behavior between Firefox and others in calling `B()`, when the call is before definition.

While trying to narrow down the cause, I read about **function hoisting** [here](http://statichtml.com/2011/spidermonkey-function-hoisting.html), which says Firefox doesnt do hoisting when inside an `if` block, but the definition was never inside the `if` statement in my case, so Im confused.

Comment: Placing a function declaration in a block (i.e., not in top-level code in a function or global code) is [not legal ECMAScript](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks), and browsers that allow it (i.e., all of them) are providing a custom extension of the language specification. You are observing two different custom extensions of the language. The statement "*Firefox doesnt do hoisting when inside an `if` block*" is a little misleading: Firefox doesn't do hoisting in *any* block, including `for`.

Comment: @apsillers - So is it safe to assume this issue is **solely** because Firefox doesnt do hoisting inside any block?

Comment: From the code you have posted here, yes, lack of hoisting for function declarations in blocks would account for the observed behavior perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox does not hoist function declarations outside of `for` blocks either. ECMA standard says it's okay. The documentation you linked to is not applicable only to `if` blocks, but `for` blocks as well.

Comment: You've got a couple of statements in reverse: you mean *in*-side, and the ECMAScript spec does *not* allow function declarations inside blocks.

Comment: "Firefox does not hoist function declarations [to] outside of `for` blocks [from inside the block]. ECMA standard says it's okay [that this behavior happens]." I don't think I was wrong. I just wasn't clear.